# Why is my Azure function not recording the correct exception in App Insights?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

Let's say my function is the following:

```
public static void Run([QueueTrigger(queueName, Connection = connection)]string message, 
                       TraceWriter logger) {
    throw new CustomException();
}
```

Here's what the log looks like:

```
SomeTime [Error] ExceptionNameSpace.CustomException ---> System.Exception
```

When I go to App Insights and view the exception breakdown, I find this failed request under the "Exception" type. I don't even see a CustomException type listed! Why is my exception being transformed into a generic exception?

Comment: please provide your CustomException code and the screenshots on azure portal. And this line of code "throw new CustomException()" is not in try..catch block? If I directly use your code, no exceptions are sent to app insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who ran into the same issue:

I found the "solution" for this by being able to recover my original exception by querying for the outerType column in the exceptions table inside the Analytics part of App Insights. Strange that the generic exception shows up under the "type" column but "outerType" is my original exception.